# How to import private functions with import *?

Tags: python, import

When debugging, `from module import *` comes in handy. However, it only seems to import the public functions. Functions that start with `_` are not imported but I would like them to be.

How do I get all private functions to also be imported?

**Edit**
I'm fully aware `import *` is bad practice in general, but sometimes I need to identify and fix an urgent production issue and using `import *` when debugging interactively saves crucial time.

Comment: The solution is not to use `import *` at all, but import the *module*, then refer to whatever you need as `module._foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from module import *` defaults to only importing *all public* names. Specify an `__all__` sequence consisting of names (as strings) in your module globals if you need to explicitly control what names are imported. You can add private names to that list:

```
__all__ = ['PublicClass', 'public_function', '_private_function']
```

However, a better alternative is not to use `from module import *` at all. Code that relies on private names of a sibling module should just import those explicitly.

Note that using `from module import *` is generally frowned upon, as this makes it much harder to verify your code, both by human readers and by linters (static code checkers), as you can't determine what names are imported and which ones are missing.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't have write access to the source code?

Comment: @mchen: then just use explicit imports. `from module import _private_name`.

Comment: @mchen: if you *must* you can *set* `module.__all__`, but is adding one import line really that tedious?

Comment: This answer assumes that there's 'just one single function' that needs to be imported. In reality one may want to import **all** private names, even those that weren't yet invented. The use case is when creating a pass-through module, that would override some functions, but keep everything else intact. Code that's out of ours control may depend on those private names. Also add forward compatibility and DRY to the mix so you can't list the private names one-by-one.

Comment: @YakovGalka nowhere in my answer is there an assumption about a single import. The point is that private names are excluded for a reason and if the module follows the Python conventions then a proxy module doesn’t need to import those names anyway. A your proxy module would reflect the `__all__` list of the proxies module.

Comment: @YakovGalka for *specialist* edge cases you can always get the full namespace if a module using `vars()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, the question was how to import **all** private names; the OP stating that they are aware that `import *` is a bad practice. This answer suggests adding the private names one-by-one, which in some cases isn't practical. It would be more on point if you showed, for example, how to automatically initialize `__all__` with all those names, rather than re-iterating that `import *` is bad.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

```
import module
globals().update(vars(module) | globals())
```

Of-course that's [Python 3.9 syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/), [in Python 3.5+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) one can use:

```
globals().update({**vars(module), **globals()})
```

Note that I'm not just using `globals().update(vars(module))`, which will overwrite all global variables, including [import-related module attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes) like `__file__`, `__loader__`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Martijn's answer... If you want that `import *` imports **all** the symbols defined in a module, including private ones, an easy way to do this (without explicitly enumerating the names) is to put this line at the end of the module:

```py
__all__ = list(globals().keys())
```